# Excel VBA copying specific data to othe excel file

Tags: excel, vba, copy

I'm trying to copy specific rows with certain criteria that in comboboxcusworker.text to newly created excel file.
But I always get an error "out of range" on "SET TARGET = ...." line.
Need help
Here is my code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim c As Range
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim Source As Workbook
    Dim Target As Workbook

     ' Change worksheet designations as needed
    Set Source = Workbooks.Open("c:\msn\ì÷åçåú.xlsm")


flname = InputBox("Enter File Name :", "Creating New File...")
If flname <> "" Then
    Workbooks.Add
  ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="C:\MSN\" & flname
 Sheets.Add.Name = "Customer"
   End If

   Set Target = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(ComboBoxCusWorker.Text) '*Run-time error 9:Subscript out of range*

    j = 1     ' Start copying to row 1 in target sheet
    For Each c In Source.Range("y1:y10000")   ' Do 1000 rows
        If c = ComboBoxCusWorker.Text Then
            Source.Rows(c.Row).Copy Target.Rows(j)
              j = j + 1
           End If
     Next c

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I've changed the "Set Target" line to :

```
Set Target = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Customer")
```

The problem solved.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have `Dim`ed **Target** as a workbook, but are trying to set it to a worksheet.

Comment: I've changed to worksheet but still - same error "out of range"

Comment: That usually means a spelling error in the worksheet name.  Check that all characters **including spaces** match.

Comment: I've checked nothing seems to be wrong. I'm on this problem for two days now. I've checked everything...

Comment: If you **MsgBox ComboBoxCusWorker.Text** just before the `Set`, you will see what I mean.

Comment: I got new error - "run time error 1004: Application defined or object defined error. Didn't help, what it means?

Comment: It means that **ComboBoxCusWorker.Text** is either not  established or your sub cannot get to it.

Answer (score 0):

If I run this code it works

```
Dim c As Range
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim Source As Worksheet
    Dim Target As Worksheet

Sheets.Add.Name = ComboBoxCusWorker.Text

    ' Change worksheet designations as needed
    Set Source = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Customer")
    Set Target = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(ComboBoxCusWorker.Text)

    j = 1     ' Start copying to row 1 in target sheet
    For Each c In Source.Range("y1:y10000")   ' Do 1000 rows
        If c = ComboBoxCusWorker.Text Then
           Source.Rows(c.Row).Copy Target.Rows(j)
           j = j + 1
        End If
    Next c
```

What is the difference ???

Answer (score 0):

Your original code doesn’t include code to create a new worksheet, which you try to reference, this your error. Also, there is ambiguity in using ActiveWorkbook or Sheets without referencing a specific Workbook. I’ve updated your code below.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim c As Range
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim Source As Workbook
    Dim TargetBook As Workbook
    Dim Target As Worksheet

     ' Change worksheet designations as needed
    Set Source = Workbooks.Open("c:\msn\ì÷åçåú.xlsm")

flname = InputBox("Enter File Name :", "Creating New File...")
If flname <> "" Then
    Set TargetBook = Workbooks.Add
  TargetBook.SaveAs Filename:="C:\MSN\" & flname
 TargetBook.Sheets.Add.Name = "Customer"
   End If

   Set Target = TargetBook.Worksheets.Add.Name = ComboBoxCusWorker.Text

    j = 1     ' Start copying to row 1 in target sheet
    For Each c In Source.Range("y1:y10000")   ' Do 1000 rows
        If c = ComboBoxCusWorker.Text Then
            Source.Rows(c.Row).Copy Target.Rows(j)
              j = j + 1
           End If
     Next c

End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry but there is a problem with your solution:  Set Target = TargetBook.Worksheets.Add.Name = ComboBoxCusWorker.Text